# How to render to not found templte in meteor js if the requested path is not there

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, flow-router

I have a meteor website
I want to render to the not found template if user enters the url which is not the part of my website or I have not configured.

I have used flow router for the routing process.

Please help me out. how to do that
I am just a newbie in meteorjs

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
FlowRouter.route('/*',{
      name: "routename",
      action: function () {
       BlazeLayout.render('layout', {
           main: "templatename"
       });          
    }
})
```